# How to execute aggregate in mongodb in laravel framework

Tags: mongodb, laravel-4

I need to get result of following query in laravel frame work (used jenssegers library)

```
db.product.aggregate({ $group : {_id : "$catid", total : { $sum : 1}}},
                                {$sort:{total:-1}});
```

I tried to do this like this

```
return DB::connection($this - > connection)- > 
          collection($this - > collection) - > aggregate(
        '{ $group : {_id : "$catid", total : { $sum : 1 }}},{$sort:{total:-1}}'');
```

But it is giving error like **"ErrorException Undefined index: aggregate"** need to know that how to use mongodb "db.collection.aggregate"

The document of my collection is like this

```
  {
     "_id": ObjectId("5369d68611fe14ddc5f59ff9"),
     "sku": 123456,
     "productid": 1,
     "name": "name1",
     "catid": 1
 }
```

Comment: if possible.. display your database structure in question

Comment: Hi Mia, I have include a document of my collection to get an idea of the structure thank you to looking into this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access the aggregate method on the Jenssegers library via the `raw()` function.

Here is an example of an aggregate call with group, sort, limit and project. You can adapt it to your needs:

```
//Perform an aggregate function and get a cursor
$cursor = Data::raw()->aggregate([
    ['$group' =>
        ['_id' => '$name', 'count' => ['$sum' => 1]]
    ],
    ['$sort' => ['count' => -1]],
    ['$limit' => 30],
    ['$project' => ['_id' => 0,
                   'text' => '$_id',
                   'size' => '$count',
                   ]
    ],
]);

//Iterate your cursor
$current = $cursor;
do {
    echo $current; //Process each element
} while (!($current = $cursor->next()));
```

Note that using the `raw()` method requires using a cursor because it is a low-level call.

Comment: foreach ($cursor  as $document) { } is much more simpler than do while

Comment: Is there any way to pass normal aggregation string to MongoDB? like `[ { $limit: 1 } ]`

Comment: if u want to use do-while, it should be:
        
        `do {
            echo $cursor->current();
            $cursor->next();
        } while ($cursor->valid());`
        
in your case it will be: 
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException: Cannot advance a completed or failed cursor

Answer (score -3):

try something like this

```
db.product.aggregate(
     { "$group" : 
        { "_id" : "$catid", 
          "total" : { "$sum" : 1}
        }
     },
     { "$sort" : {"productid":-1} }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea but I need to execute this query using laravel frame work. I'm using jenssegers library as db connector