# sum key and group by key with Mongodb and Laravel

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-5

Having this collection -

```
{
    "_id": "5b508587de796c0006207fa7",
    "id": "1",
    "status": "pending",        
    "updated_at": "2018-07-19 13:02:40",
    "created_at": "2018-07-19 12:35:19"
},
{
    "_id": "5b508587de796c0006207fa5",
    "id": "2",
    "status": "completed",        
    "updated_at": "2018-07-19 13:02:40",
    "created_at": "2018-07-19 12:35:19"
},
```

I want to have a query that will sum the **status** key by the **id** key.

For example -

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "pending":"1"
}
```

I am using Laravel 5.5 with MongoDB

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Nanw59wJSOL). Check out Mongo's reference for [Aggregations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate), as well as the [`$group` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$status",
      sumOfStatus: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**EDIT:** After proof-reading, I'm not really sure that was what you were looking for. This [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rBxhVkd80n9) will return your a list of statuses for each `id` such as:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5",
    "completed": 3,
    "pending": 3
  }
]
```

To do so, I'm leveraging the `$cond` operator in order to conditionally `$sum` documents depending on their `status` value. One drawback is that you have to repeat this for each value. Not sure of a way around that.

Regarding the Laravel implementation, I'm definitely not a Laravel expert, but check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31464517/7152435) which shows an example on how to access the `aggregate()` method.

Comment: Thanks. any idea how can I implement it in laravel?

Comment: @J.Doe Yes I do

Comment: @AlexisFacques Tahnks for the answer. trying to figure out how to implement it with mongo

Comment: @AlexisFacques you last example closer to what I need. but still, it has a problem with sum the amount of status. (for id-5 it returns 3 completed and 3 pending)

Comment: @Maayans I've updated the [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rBxhVkd80n9), this should now work as intended :)

Comment: @AlexisFacques Thank you!! saved me =)