# Unsupported projection option in laravel mongodb

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I am running following query in mongodb collection and I am using this package https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb to communicate with mongodb in laravel.

```
$ibQuery = $this->model->project(['message_count' =>
                [
                    '$size' => [
                        '$ifNull' => ['$messages', []]
                    ]
                ]
            ])
            ->get();
return $ibQuery;
```

and I am getting this error.

```
exception: "MongoDB\Driver\Exception\CommandException"
file: "/opt/lampp/htdocs/my-project/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/Find.php"
line: 337
message: "Unsupported projection option: message_count: { size: { ifNull: [ "messages", [] ] } }"
```

Comment: `$size` and `$ifNull` are aggregation operators, you cannot use them in `find`. I am not familiar with laravel, thus I don't know how to invoke `aggregate` Looks like there is no native support for aggregation pipelines, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534784/how-to-execute-aggregate-in-mongodb-in-laravel-framework/31464517

Answer (score 0):

In case if anyone's facing same issue, after updating php version to **7.4.13** from **7.3.x** solved this error. thanks.